# PHP Mysql multiple insert with foreach not working

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code - I'm attempting to attach a bunch of user_id 's to a piece of content.

```
if (empty($errors)) // If everything's OK.
{ 
    foreach($_POST['userId'] as $row)
    {
        $query = " ('".$row[learner_id]."', '".$postId."', '".$id."' ),";
    }

    $query = substr_replace($query,"",-1);
    $mysql_return = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO subs (userId, postId, account_id ) VALUES ".$query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Would love any help you could give - it's not working...

Comment: What error do you have? I guess you have an extra `,` at then end of your statement.

Comment: Please define "its not working"

Comment: he error message I get is "mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given" on that last line...

Answer (score 1):

And how's it not working? Syntax error? Silently puking? You're not escaping your POST data, so if any of those contain at least one single quote, that'll cause a syntax error right there, plus leaving you wide open for sql injection attacks.

Or maybe a foreign key check is failing... many possibilities, but you haven't given us nearly enough info to tell. What error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: The error message I get is "mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given" on that last line... (I'll also add the mysqli_real_escape_string to the post data)

Comment: The first argument to most `mysqli_*()` functions in procedural mode should be the database link handle.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see several issues:

1. You are not using parameters or escaping, opening yourself up WIDE to sql injection attacks.  See `mysqli_real_escape_string`.
2. What are you possibly sending to $_POST['userId'] that would make itself an array?
3. Unless `learner_id` is a constant, then this is a syntax error.  If it is an array key, put it in quotes.
4. Where are `$postId` and `$id` coming from ?

Comment: Thank. 1. I know I've got to escape the post data. 2. The info sent there is the Id's from a form - I can verify it's being sent in an array. 3. learner_id was a copy/paste mistake, should read userId... it does in my script. 4. $postId and $id are constants

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) is the identifier returned by `mysqli_connect`, whereas you're just giving it the query directly.

It should be like this,

```
$link = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db");
$mysql_return = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO subs (userId, postId, ac...
```